# Setting up colspan in HTML table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

Having some trouble figuring out what the grid is like for using `colspan`, so that I can evenly align my items.

HTML

```
<table class="table MethodList" ng-repeat="method in api.methods">
   <tr>
      <td colspan=4 style="font-weight:bold">{{method.name}}</td>
      <td colspan=8>{{method.desc}}</td>
   <tr>
      <td colspan=4></td>
      <td colspan=8 style="background:#E6E6DA">{{method.parameters}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan=4></td>
      <td colspan=8>{{method.additional}}</td>
   </tr>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What this does

[image]

As you can see, the following texts are pushed back each row further and I do not know why. I am trying to just keep the initial value (index, create, confirm, choose) as the only item in colspan=4, then everything else to be after that.

I also have bootstrap included in case they use some nice template.

Comment: you have an extra closing tag :  </tr> check it please

Comment: @Austin You don't have an extra close tag, you have a mis-placed close tag. Your second two rows are currently within your first row, which is invalid and probably the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a misplaced closing **tr** tag `</tr>` at the end of your table.
Please fix it and check again to see if the layout is displayed correctly

Your code should became something like this:

```
<table class="table MethodList" ng-repeat="method in api.methods">
   <tr>
      <td colspan=4 style="font-weight:bold">{{method.name}}</td>
      <td colspan=8>{{method.desc}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan=4></td>
      <td colspan=8 style="background:#E6E6DA">{{method.parameters}}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan=4></td>
      <td colspan=8>{{method.additional}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not an extra close tag, it's a mis-placed close tag. It needs a closing tag on the first TR.